# intelliJ Error when build the Project - Cause: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, spring, stack-overflow

Im using IntelliJ On Mac OS.

I have been getting java.lang.StackOverflowError upon building the project.

i think this happened after developing the thread part.. but codes are fine, and tried build on Eclipse at Windows, works good..

ive changed the value for "Shared build process VM options" to **-Xss4m**

and also added VM options to Tomcat server

**-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss4M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled**

but keep getting the message like below

java 1.8 and lombok was working fine

```
// lombok
    compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.28'
    annotationProcessor group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.28'
```

```
Java 1.8
gradle

IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.6 (Ultimate Edition)
```

```
Cause: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:532)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:490)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:286)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:1)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:394)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:292)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:532)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:490)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:286)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:1)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:394)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:292)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:532)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:490)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:286)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:1)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:394)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:292)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:532)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:490)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:286)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:1)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:394)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:292)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:532)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:490)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:286)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:1)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:394)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:292)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:532)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:490)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:286)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:1)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:394)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:292)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:532)
    ....
```

Comment: That looks like a Lombok compiler bug.  1) Search the Lombok issue tracker for relevant bugs. Check on resolution / workarounds.  2) If 1. fails, try to turn the code you are trying to compile into a minimal example. (Cut bits out, see if the exception is still there, repeat)  Then submit an bug report via the Lombok issue tracker including your minimal example.

Comment: It might be this bug: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/2453

Comment: In a comment on a related issue: *"If you have a long statements (a lot of dots: e.g. builder with lot of fileds). Split it into multiple smaller statements."*